# Building a sum index in R

Tags: r, indexing, sum

I want to build a sumindex in R from several variables of my data set, e.g. `v110`, `v111` etc.  For this I have coded the variables as dummy variables, which are now called `_recode`, to form three categories with an average index.  These are the variables ending in `contacts`, `holiday` and `longystays`.  These must be weighted with `0.3` or `0.4`.  In the end I want to create the sum index called `transnat`, consisting of the 3 categories. I know that when I multiply by 10 I will expand the range at the end.  But my output shows a range from -17 to 10.

This is my code:

```
data_issp$transnat_contacts <- (data_issp$v110_recode - data_issp$v111_recode - data_issp$v112_recode - data_issp$v113_recode) * 0.3

data_issp$transnat_holiday <- (data_issp$v119_recode) * 0.3

data_issp$transnat_longstays <- (data_issp$v115_recode - data_issp$v116_recode - data_issp$v117_recode) * 0.4

table(data_issp$transnat_contacts)
table(data_issp$transnat_holiday)
table(data_issp$transnat_longstays)
```

Output:
[image: output]

```
data_issp_transnat <- (data_issp$transnat_contacts + data_issp$transnat_holiday + data_issp$transnat_longstays) * 10

table(data_issp_transnat)
```

Final output:
[image: final output]

Comment: Please do not post an image of code/data/errors: it cannot be copied or searched (SEO), it breaks screen-readers, and it may not fit well on some mobile devices. Ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 (and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please just include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `dput(head(x))` or `data.frame(...)`) directly.

Comment: Inline images, other minor formatting and grammar edits